# PHP: what happens if required script stops because of timeout

Tags: php, timeout, require

Scenario: a php script with som pre-code, a require xxxx.php; and some postcode. Wanting and believing that because of using require and not include, the script will stop at the "require" statement if xxxx.php times out - is that correct?

Or asked in another way: is a timeout the same as the script throwing an error?

Comment: timeout in `require` and `include`, how can it possible?

Comment: why not? the required script may as easily time out as the "main" script, no? In this case, the main script and the required script are on two different servers, one a commandline windows php, the other on a webserver...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

max_execution_time integer

This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run before it is terminated by the parser. This helps prevent poorly written scripts from tying up the server. The default setting is 30. When running PHP from the command line the default setting is 0.

The maximum execution time is not affected by system calls, stream operations etc. Please see the set_time_limit() function for more details.

You can not change this setting with ini_set() when running in safe mode. The only workaround is to turn off safe mode or by changing the time limit in the php.ini.

Your web server can have other timeout configurations that may also interrupt PHP execution. Apache has a Timeout directive and IIS has a CGI timeout function. Both default to 300 seconds. See your web server documentation for specific details.

[Official Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) for `set_time_limit()`

Comment: yes, I know ... :-) The question is: what kind of error does a timeout throw? Will the main script with the require inside STOP if the required script times out? (that is infact what I want it to do)...?

Comment: Yes I believe it will make the main script stop. Imagine the "required/included" file has a copy/paste in the main script.

Comment: yes, true, but not 100%, as included would not make the main script stop. But you are probably right, also what I assume, just wanted, if possible, to get it confirmed... :-)